# Google App Engine Datastore - key value passing in HTML to js function

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using Jinja2 GAE Datastore.
In my template html javascript script section - I want to call a function triggered by onclick and pass 2 arguments.  The second argument is a GAE key value.  It seems the key is retrieved but then when it is passed as an argument - I get an uncaught reference error undefined  - almost seems like it views it as an undefined variable?

```
html_output += "<input class='filter_submit first_level' name='first_input' type='button' onclick='pass_hidden(1,{{one.key()}})' value='{{one.name1}}'></input><br />";
```

HERE IS THE FUNCTION CALLED BY THE ONCLICK...

```
function pass_hidden(num,key_val) {

alert('in pass_hidden function');   
        var add_html;
        if (num=='1') {
            add_html += "<input type='hidden' value='key_val' name='second_input'></input><input type='hidden' value='1' name='heading_number'></input>";
        }

        else if (num=='2') {
            add_html +="<input type='hidden' value='key_val' name='second_input'></input><input type='hidden' value='2' name='heading_number'></input>";
        }

        else if (num=='3') {
            add_html +="<input type='hidden' value='key_val' name='second_input'></input><input type='hidden' value='3' name='heading_number'></input>";
        }

        add_html +="<input type='hidden' name='heading_type' value='subject'></input>";
        /*$("hidden_inputs").append(add_html);  */
        document.getElementById("hidden_inputs").innerHTML = add_html;

        document.userchoices.submit();

    }
```

Comment: Is this all the code you have? How is that string added to the DOM? Where is `pass_hidden` defined? What is the output of `{{one.key()}}`?

Comment: sure - the output of {{one.key()}} is the datastore key-- agtkZXZ-bXN0c2FwcHIsCxIQTGV2ZWxfMV9IZWFkaW5ncxgGDAsSEExldmVsXzJfSGVhZGluZ3MYCww    and I've added the additional code to my original question - many thanks for taking a look!!!

Comment: Do you think it's because of the dash (-)?? (agtkZXA-....).  How do I fix that when it's part of the key?

Comment: To be more exact the error was "Uncaught ReferenceError: agtkZXZ is not defined " so I'm thinking the dash (-) is the problem but don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly replace your line with this one and it should work:

```
html_output += "<input class='filter_submit first_level' name='first_input' type='button' onclick='pass_hidden(1,\"%s\")' value='%s'></input><br />" % (one.key(), one.name1)
```

You are using the template variables inside the Python code and will not work, so I exchanged them using the string format.

You should also always view the source of the generated template to make sure that everything there is as expected.

Comment: so I tried, but didn't work.  the data in one is actually populated with data from the server and one stands for the data in one iteration of extracting that data.  It is retrieving the one.key() data fine but it is still indicating that it is undefined.  frustrating. For some reason, it is seeing it as a variable?  (instead of a string value.